# Bootstrap 3 a href link not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu bar at the top of a page created with bootstrap 3. One of the menu items is a search form (shown below) that is revealed when a cursor hovers over it. It works fine but I am trying to figure out how I can take the user to `search.php` if the menu item is clicked. How can I do this? Thanks.

```
    <li class="dropdown">
  <a href="search.php" class="dropdown-toggle js-activated">Search</a>

  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <form id="search" class="navbar-form search" role="search" action="" method="GET">
      <input type="search" id="searchquery" name="searchquery" class="form-control" placeholder="Search editors">
      <button type="submit" id="name_search" name="name_search" class="btn btn-default btn-submit icon-right-open"></button>
    </form>

    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div id="searchquery_results"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.dropdown-menu -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.dropdown-menu -->
</li>
<!-- /.searchbox -->
```

Comment: Bootstrap prevents the default action `onclick` for dropdown toggles, since this is how you trigger the dropdown menu. How can you toggle the dropdown on clicl *and* go to `search.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('a:contains("Search")').click(function(){
   window.location.href = $(this).data('href');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a data-href="search.php" class="dropdown-toggle js-activated">Search</a>

  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <form id="search" class="navbar-form search" role="search" action="" method="GET">
      <input type="search" id="searchquery" name="searchquery" class="form-control" placeholder="Search editors">
      <button type="submit" id="name_search" name="name_search" class="btn btn-default btn-submit icon-right-open"></button>
    </form>

    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div id="searchquery_results"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.dropdown-menu -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.dropdown-menu -->
</li>
</ul>
```

Instead of `href`, please you `data-href` & using `jQuery` click event redirect the page to `search.php`.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
action="search.php"
```

and:

```
<li class="dropdown" onclick="location.href='search.php';">
```

Comment: This will cause the `onclick` handler to trigger if a user clicks into the form field.